# How can I cluster data, that is based on already hierarchically clustered input data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a raster with 24 different classes, they are based on an agglomerative clustering. That means some classes are more similar to eachother than to some other classes.

I now have polygons that overlap the raster and I counted for each polygon the number and type of cells that overlap per polygon. The result is a df with every row showing the numbers of cells per class, see below.

```
,1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23,24,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0
3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0
4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
12,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
15,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0
17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
18,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0
21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0
25,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0
29,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

How can I now cluster these into different classes, considering that some of the classes are more similar to each other. I also have the similarity matrix based on the distance on the dendrogram from the agglomerative clustering. 1 means high similarity, 0 is most dissimilar.  How can i take this similarity in the clustering into consideration?

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
0,1.0,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.12963769221283028,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.07534643156694784,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.12963769221283028,0.12963769221283028,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.10329627953233886,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
1,0.07534643156694784,1.0,0.03710951024156955,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.13092729323753732,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.07534643156694784,0.07534643156694784,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.07534643156694784,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
2,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,1.0,0.03710951024156955,0.1251892745044139,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.1251892745044139,0.1251892745044139,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
3,0.12963769221283028,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,1.0,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.07534643156694784,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.18414169525252058,0.1538739511256067,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.10329627953233886,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
4,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.1251892745044139,0.03710951024156955,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.12879269409291,0.19915921947536172,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
5,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.008743874054086248,0.047438421748178285,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.10336542840193345,0.002348592922684922,0.0
6,0.05746448928552134,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.05746448928552134,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.05746448928552134,0.05746448928552134,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.05746448928552134,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
7,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.09454014211514201,0.09454014211514201,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
8,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.008743874054086248,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.03631562309248371,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.0
9,0.07071292864963602,0.07071292864963602,0.03710951024156955,0.07071292864963602,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.07071292864963602,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.07071292864963602,0.07071292864963602,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.07071292864963602,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
10,0.07534643156694784,0.13092729323753732,0.03710951024156955,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,1.0,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.07534643156694784,0.07534643156694784,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.07534643156694784,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
11,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,1.0,0.008743874054086248,0.002348592922684922,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.002348592922684922,0.008743874054086248,0.008743874054086248,0.002348592922684922,0.0
12,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.047438421748178285,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.008743874054086248,1.0,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.047438421748178285,0.002348592922684922,0.0
13,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,1.0,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.021182332731192174,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.006841423546764354,0.0
14,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.1251892745044139,0.03710951024156955,0.12879269409291,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,1.0,0.12879269409291,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
15,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.1251892745044139,0.03710951024156955,0.19915921947536172,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.09454014211514201,0.014828560352019916,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.12879269409291,1.0,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
16,0.12963769221283028,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.18414169525252058,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.07534643156694784,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,1.0,0.1538739511256067,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.10329627953233886,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
17,0.12963769221283028,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.1538739511256067,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.07534643156694784,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.1538739511256067,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.10329627953233886,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
18,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.03631562309248371,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.008743874054086248,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.0
19,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.021182332731192174,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,1.0,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.006841423546764354,0.0
20,0.10329627953233886,0.07534643156694784,0.03710951024156955,0.10329627953233886,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.05746448928552134,0.03710951024156955,0.014828560352019916,0.07071292864963602,0.07534643156694784,0.008743874054086248,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.03710951024156955,0.03710951024156955,0.10329627953233886,0.10329627953233886,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,1.0,0.014828560352019916,0.002348592922684922,0.0
21,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.10336542840193345,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.008743874054086248,0.047438421748178285,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.014828560352019916,0.0331504233805512,0.002348592922684922,0.014828560352019916,1.0,0.002348592922684922,0.0
22,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.006841423546764354,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,0.006841423546764354,0.002348592922684922,0.002348592922684922,1.0,0.0
23,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
```